# how to do HTTPS post/get in java.

Tags: java, sockets, https

Is it possible to do https get/post by just using J2SE without any web components eg.`servlets` and other stuff. If possible then how to do?

If I am using `sockets` to send and receive into then there will be no get/post. I am I right in saying that?

My scenario is described below.

Application A and B running in same server. app A sends a https post to app B. What should app B do to get that URL and process the request parameters? Again no `servlets`. both the application will standalone application with no web interface. How will app A hit my server?

Comment: Why don't you want to use servlets? They are the standard way in Java to process http(s) requests. If it's just the secure communication you want, you could use sockets in conjunction with SSL, i.e. `SSLSocket` and the like.

Comment: +1 on the comment by Thomas, because with the socket and thread handling you'll basically be writing an embedded web server. Just use one like Jetty.

Comment: @Thomas Y I m not using servlets? as I said mmy app is not a web application. Its a interface application. some thing like middle ware.

Comment: Well, http is a web protocol and one could argue that a server that listens and answers to http requests is a web server...

Comment: Using an HTTPS connection between two applications on the same computer does not make much sense as you can not use SSL certificates in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the bare minimum you'd need is a ServerSocket (or SSLServerSocket) and HttpURLConnection (or HttpsURLConnection). If you're implementing something really trivial, then it shouldn't be too much work to implement a simple service with a custom ServerSocket.

Now that i think about it, i've actually done that once. Totally doable :)

Answer (score 2):

No offense but that is what Servlets do, that is the entire reason for their existence. I am sure there is some back-assward hack to simulate a Servlet, but it kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: I cant deploy this app in web application. NO JSP's r involved.This appplication will serve as a middlware where front end will be a ivrcall flow.

Comment: @Arun: I think you are mixing J2EE/WAR/EAR with the JavaServlet concept. You can have a standalone app containing a Java webserver (e.g. TJWS) and serveral servlets. Everything in one JAR.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your suggestion. After lot of deliberations we decided to deploy in web container. So will be using servlets. Also we decided to move the application B to a different server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Message Queue to acheive what you want. 1st application can send http request to a message queue and 2nd application can check the queue for any waiting request.

check apache Active MQ for further reference.

http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html